# Get Image Dimensions (Height and Width) Js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have searched for this, but every time I implement the code it return 24 as height and width as 237 when I upload `400X400` image.

```
$(document).on('change','#tt' , function(){
    var img = document.getElementById('tt');
    var nheight = img.clientHeight;
    var nwidth = img.clientWidth;
    alert(nheight)
    alert(nwidth)
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="tt" name="tt" >
```

Is anyone know how can I get 400 as height and 400 as width in alert box when I upload `400X400` image. Any help is really much appreciated.....

Comment: You trying to get width and height of input not image.

Comment: Got that now..thanks. @Mohammad

Comment: img.naturalWidth and img.naturalHeight is correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Onchange event of file upload creating a Image object and attach uploaded file object as src to image object and then onload event of image object find height and width of image.

Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$(document).on('change','#tt' , function(){    
    var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            alert("width : "+this.width + " and height : " + this.height);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="tt" name="tt" >
```

Comment: [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) is an experimental technology and doesn't support old version of browser.

Comment: It support to all latest browser. You can refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Answer (score 1):

```
var nheight = img.clientHeight;
var nwidth = img.clientWidth;
```

will just get you the dimension.

Refer this -

Try

```
var x = document.getElementById("myImg").naturalWidth;
```

the naturalHeight property to return the original height of an image, or the height property to set or return the value of the height attribute of an image

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_naturalwidth.asp